Is there a reverse mapping of key codes or escape sequences to common keyboard keys?
I am using fish for my shell, so I have an easy way the escape sequences or key codes for various key presses using the fish_key_reader builtin.
What I'm looking for is the reverse. Is there a way I can see a list of what escape sequences or key codes would correspond to physical key presses?
For example, I can see that \b is received by the shell when I press "Control+Backspace" and \xF7 is received when just pressing "Backspace."
Wikipedia has some of them, so I can see how "Alt+Shift+Delete" produces \e\[3\;4~, but there are clearly many more.
I did see this previous post (Are ASCII escape sequences and control characters pairings part of a standard?), and the links in the comments, but they only seem to cover standard ASCII non-printing control characters.
Ideally, with the reverse mapping, I could write custom keymapping for combinations that are not well handled, such as "Control+Shift+Backspace" (also just sends \b) so they don't interfere with existing ones but give me added functionality.
